# What does the word “doofosity” mean?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology, nonce-words

I have already tried to look up *doofosity* in many dictionaries but met with no success, so I’m asking here: what is the meaning of *doofosity*?

Comment: It is obviously an adjective because of the 'ity' ending. A [*doofus*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Doofus) (AmE) is a stupid person, so my guess is that it means stupidity. A link (in your question) to the source text would be useful and will probably prevent your question from being down-voted.

Comment: It is apparently the measure of how much of a doof someone is.

Comment: @Mick: No - it's obviously a ***noun***. From the dictionary.com entry for **-ity**: [a suffix used to form **abstract nouns** expressing **state or condition**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ity) - in this case, the state of being a doofus, with ***u*** switched to ***o*** to give a more "natural" looking coinage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right.

Comment: It's clearly the existential state one enters when one's everyday doofusness evolves into a continuous practice of doofusism.

Comment: @Mick I took your first answer to be an ironic, post-modern illustration of the term itself. Well played!

Comment: @deadrat Irony? What's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Doofus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doofus)***, also ***dufus*** is an AnE slang term from the '60s which is both a noun and a modifier:

(modifier)

> - Many another dufus play among friends

(noun)

> - A fool; idiot; airhead, birdbrain, boob: *He'll do his best to make you feel like a doofus/ But this is the doofus you have to deal with, so hush up/ I have to be in front of this self-important doofis with his portable phone/ I felt like such a dufus/ when some big, loud, popcorn-chuggin' doof and his date sit in front of me*.

Origin:

> - [1960s+; probably related to doo-doo and goofus]

***[Doofusity](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&ei=65QwWKrMIoGfUrO8h-gM&q=doofusity%20%20&oq=doofusity%20%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..41.10709.11609.0.12256.7.7.0.0.0.0.293.1012.2j4j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..2.5.583...0i19k1j0i13i5i10i30i19k1j30i10k1.973tX3PGcnQ)*** is the quite rare abstract noun from doufus that refer to the quality of being a doofus.

Comment: Note that the OP's word was "doofosity", not "doofusity".  The "o" makes for an easier-to-pronounce word and also is consistent with the use of the "-osity" suffix in other cases.